# About updating a node-webkit app

Tags: node.js, updates, node-webkit

I want to set auto-updates up for my apps before I release. I'm a budding programmer, so when I looked into node-webkit-updater I was pretty confused. It seems under-documented to me. Can someone explain the overall update mechanism that it helps implement?

As an alternative to node-webkit-updater, I was thinking of creating my own update system. I kinda like how Apple handles extension updates and I was thinking about replicating it. This would involve putting a JSON/XML manifest file on Amazon S3 along with the latest versions of the app for all platforms. The app checks the file at startup and replaces itself with the new version.

Is the latter sound plausible? Am I better off going with node-webkit-updater? If so, can someone explain it to me please? My app is a Mac + Windows project.

Answer (score 0):

This is what we did:

1. The first script of the page checks a custom "manifest" (.txt file) on the server, which contains some arbitrary text, e.g. version number.
2. If this value differs from a local version of the manifest, then download a .zip file from server. (The zip contains the latest nwjs website. You could have a separate one for each platform).
3. Unzip into a local directory (we use 7za command line util).
4. Set window.location.href to above local directory (index.html).

Answer (score -2):

I know this is a old question, but here is the answer :)

https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-webkit-updater

Comment: I mentioned in my question that this package confused me. Have you used it before? I would appreciate a clean and simple, detailed explanation of how this updater works.

Comment: @Antrikshy, just read the documentation on the Github page. If you download the packed you will get a working example. :)

Comment: Download what? I have seen the example file with the implementation. But I can't get a higher level understanding of what goes where and what I should put on a server.